# Is avoiding global variables as simple as just putting every variable in a struct or class?

Tags: c++

I don't really understand global variables. Why would anyone ever make one? It seems you could just put every variable in the entire program in a struct or a class?

Is this the right way to do things? It makes my code a lot more annoying to write, but it seems to solve a lot of problems.

Comment: There is a right use for every tool. There is a right use for global variables too. What is that right use? That's going to be your decision to make. If you reach a conclusion that, for a given task, a global variable is the right solution, then that's the right use. There is no absolute ruler of C++ that issues decrees as to what's the right way or the wrong way to do so. This is an ***educated*** decision for everyone to make, so educate yourself on the pluses and minuses of global variables, and make your decisions accordingly.

Comment: Replacing N global variables, by one global struct doesn't change the fact that it is global at the end... It might allow to pass that struct to functions easily than having to pass N variable though. but it is unfortunately not so simple to remove global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Putting global variables inside structs is just a way of *organizing* them, and your global namespace ends up less polluted. However, those structs are still global, so it doesn't solve all problems. It's up to you to decide how and when to use them, and if it's a good design choice.

Comment: Well then ill put those structs in structs in structs in classes and in a struct. Now I have one global struct.

Comment: You'd still have one big global struct, and that might not be very useful. Global variables aren't necessarily something bad, but they can turn into something bad very quickly if you're not responsible with their use. What I mean is that you can use them if you want, since it's a design choice, but it should be a conscious decision, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables just mean variables with a life time as same as your application. They are not necessarily the same category of things.

Example:

- You have a global variable called `configs` -- holding all your configuration like your color preferences, max thread number you want for certain purposes
- You also have a global parser -- you want to parse same type of data here and there
- You also have a global thread pool

These are things of very distinct nature. Putting them in a struct called `globalVars` is not the most readable way to organize source code, in my opinion

Comment: What makes a global variable global isn’t its lifespan, but rather the fact that it can be accessed directly from anywhere in the source code.